# Calculo Juros Compostos PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma calculadora de juros compostos em PHP, onde eu preciso preciso calcular o valor do investimento inicial, o investimento mensal, o período e por porcentagem de juros a cada mês.

A calculadora realiza a soma do valor investido inicialmente + o valor que será investido a cada mês + o juros sobre os dois valores anteriores (juros sobre juros).

Calculadora que estou usando como base: https://mepoupenaweb.uol.com.br/simuladores-online-de-investimentos/simulador-de-juros-composto/

EDIT1: o Código está imprimindo um valor muito diferente do site que estou como base, por exemplo: se eu utilizar o valores:

- Investimento inicial: 7.500
- Investimento mensal: 500
- Meses: 7
- Taxa de juros: 15%

Meu código retorna:

- Valor investido: 11.000,00
- Juros: 13.280,16
- Total acumulado: 24.280,16

O site que estou de base retorna:

- Valor investido: 11.000,00
- Juros: 761,51
- Total investido: 11.761,51

Está muito discrepante os valores.

```
 <form method="post" action="juros-compostos.php">
<label for="">Investimento Inicial</label>
<input type="number" name="investimento_inicial">

<label for="">Investimento Mensal</label>
<input type="number" name="investimento_mensal">

<label for="">Por quanto tempo?</label>
<input type="number" name="meses">

<label for="">Rentabilidade <span>Ao Mês</span></label>
<input type="number" name="taxa_de_juros">

<button type="submit">Calcular</button>

<?php

$investimento_inicial = floatval($_POST['investimento_inicial']);
$investimento_mensal = floatval($_POST['investimento_mensal']);
$meses = ($_POST['meses']);
$taxa_de_juros = floatval($_POST['taxa_de_juros']);

$investimento_acumulado = $investimento_inicial + $investimento_mensal;

$investimento_acumulado2 = $investimento_inicial + $investimento_mensal * $meses;

$juros_compostos_total = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $meses; $i++) {
    $juros_compostos = $investimento_acumulado * $taxa_de_juros / 100;
    $juros_compostos_total += $juros_compostos;
    $investimento_acumulado += $juros_compostos;
}

$valor_a_receber = $investimento_acumulado2 + $juros_compostos_total;

echo "Valor Investido: " . number_format($investimento_acumulado2, 2, ",", ".") . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo "Total dos juros é: " . number_format($juros_compostos_total, 2, ",", ".") . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo "Total do valor a receber é: " . number_format($valor_a_receber, 2, ",", ".") . "<br>" . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Qual erro está dando? O que precisa? Seja mais claro

Comment: Gabriel, bom dia. Acabei de adicionar mais algumas informações sobre o erro.

Comment: Exatamente, esta meio confuso a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa ajustar a lógica. Se eu pegar o valor inicial como 7000 e fizer investimentos mensais de 500, a 15% de juros, no primeiro mês os 15% vão ser sobre o valor inicial (7000), e os juros calculados (1050) vão gerar o acumulado para o próximo mês, junto com o investimento mensal (7000 + 1050 + 500)

No próximo mês, o valor inicial é de 8550. A lógica é a mesma para os demais períodos.

Abaixo tem um exemplo, com base no seu código.

```
<?php
$investimento_inicial = 7000;
$investimento_mensal = 500;
$meses = 7;
$taxa_de_juros = 15;

$investimento_acumulado = $investimento_inicial;
$investimento_acumulado2 = $investimento_inicial + ($investimento_mensal * $meses);
$juros_compostos_total = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $meses; $i++) {
    $juros_compostos = ($investimento_acumulado * $taxa_de_juros) / 100;
    $juros_compostos_total += $juros_compostos;
    $investimento_acumulado += $juros_compostos + $investimento_mensal;
}

$valor_a_receber = $investimento_acumulado2 + $juros_compostos_total;

echo "Valor Investido: " . number_format($investimento_acumulado2, 2, ",", ".") . "<br>" . "<br>";
echo "Total dos juros é: " . number_format($juros_compostos_total, 2, ",", ".") . "<br>" . "<br>";
echo "Total do valor a receber é: " . number_format($valor_a_receber, 2, ",", ".") . "<br>" . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Bins, muito obrigado. Realmente eu estava me esquecendo desse detalhe.